# javascript namespace as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, introspection

I have the following namespace (com.myCompany.myProject):

```
var com = {
  myCompany: {
    myProject: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
      o: function() {
      }
    }
  }
};
```

For example, I have the following code:

```
var self = com.myCompany.myProject;
```

How can I show this namespace as a string, e.g. "com.myCompany.myProject" ?

I've tried JSON.stringify() but it isn't that I looked for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.
An object has no way of knowing where it is stored.

If you need this kind of functionality, you have to store it somewhere in the object.

```
var com = {
  myCompany: {
    myProject: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
      '_namespace': 'com.myCompany.myProject',
      o: function() {
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As seanizer says, this is not possible.  Here are some related things that are possible, though:

index property as a string:

```
var self = com["myCompany"]["myProject"];

// or even...
var myCo = "myCompany";
var myPr = "myProject";
var self = com[myCo][myPr];
alert(myCo + "." + myPr);
```

get all properties of an object as strings:

```
for(var p in com) {
    alert(p.toString());
}
```

Will either of those help you?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you need, but hey, it may. Ext has a method called Ext.namespace, aliased as Ext.ns. It works like the following

Ext.ns('com.app.package');
com.app.package.Clazz = function() {};

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Ext.html#method-Ext-namespace

If this will help you, use their source code as inspiration.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I used it before, very useful. But it doesn't that I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

You asked how, here's the simplest way I can think of.  It involves eval but please don't judge on that basis:

```
var ns = 'com.myCompany.myProject'
    ,self = eval(ns);

console.log(self.x); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, I want to use an object map to avoid having magical strings in my code. For example I want to have a map of messages like:

```
var message = {
  configuration:
  {
    pdms: 
    {
      type: {
        getTypes: {},
        getDatabases: {}
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Now instead of using a string like:

> "message.configuration.pdms.type.getTypes"

I want to use:

```
message.configuration.pdms.type.getTypes
```

And convert that to a string. For that I use the following utility function. Note that the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#) lib is required.

```
var objectToString = (orig, string, obj) => {
  var parse = (orig, string, obj) => {
    return _.map(_.keys(orig), (key) => {
      if (_.isEmpty(orig[key])) {
        return orig[key] === obj ? string + '.' + key : '';
      } else {
        return objectToString(orig[key], string + '.' + key, obj);
      }
    });
  };
  return _.chain(parse(orig, string, obj))
          .flatten()
          .find ((n) => {return n.length > 0;})
          .value();
};
```

To make it more convenient, I partial apply that function with the source object to turn to strings and the root namespace.

```
var messageToString = _.partial(objectToString, message, 'message');

messageToString(message.configuration.pdms.type.getTypes);
// returns: 'message.configuration.pdms.type.getTypes'
```